# Visual Studio threads window empty?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I'm not sure why but my threads window in Visual Studio is empty? Is there a way I can see all my threads whilst debug? I'm not even sure why it isn't showing any, I have around 5 threads running in my application.

[image: example]

Comment: Set a breakpoint

Comment: Where? I'm using the threads window because I can't find the threads in the first place, I have over 1,000 files in my project.

Comment: When you took the screenshot, was your app still running, or had you hit "pause"?

Comment: It was in debugging mode, I never hit pause.

Comment: Mine stopped working for a while and returned I assumed something at work which blocks a lot of admin access and stuff had interfered with it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pause your application first

You can either set a breakpoint and wait until it gets hit, or click the Pause button to break immediately.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f.aspx

> In the Threads window, you can examine and work with threads in the
>   application that you are debugging.